# bubble sort with with multiple conditions in for loop

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

Implementation 1

```cpp
using namespace std;
void bubble_sort(vector<int> &a, int n)
{
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 1; (j <= i) and (a[j - 1] > a[j]); j++)
        {
                std::swap(a[j], a[j - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

This doesnt sort the given vector at all.

Implementation 2

```cpp
using namespace std;
void bubble_sort(vector<int> &a, int n)
{
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++)
        {
             if(a[j - 1] > a[j])    
                std::swap(a[j], a[j - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

But this works as expected. THe issue seems to be with the multiple conditions in the for loop. I've never encountered any issues when chaining multiple conditions in the for loop.
Can i know what the problem with the first implementation is

Comment: In the first case, the nested loop will stop immediately after finding an ordered pair of numbers. In the second case it will proceed to the end.

Comment: Did you try to debug the program?

Comment: Yes I did. My question was answered by @bereal.

Comment: You know the feeling: When you see something not for the first time; you know it's there; But you are still surprised to see it... That's how it feels every time to see C++' [Alternative operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j = 1; (j <= i) and (a[j - 1] > a[j]); j++) {
    std::swap(a[j], a[j - 1]);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
int j = 1;
while (true)
    if (!(j <= i and a[j - 1] > a[j])) { break; }
    std::swap(a[j], a[j - 1]);
    j++;
}
```

whereas

```
for (int j = 1; j <= i ; j++) {
     if(a[j - 1] > a[j])    
        std::swap(a[j], a[j - 1]);
}
```

is equivalent to

```
int j = 1;
while (true)
    if (!(j <= i)) { break; }
    if (a[j - 1] > a[j])) {
        std::swap(a[j], a[j - 1]);
    }
    j++;
}
```